# problem setting up firebase for iOS in VS Code

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code

Working on a project that needs to link to firebase.  I am using VS Code 2 with Xcode 9.3.  I have followed the steps from console.firebase.google.com but get the below error messages.

Can someone explain what I did wrong or maybe I need to update something.

```
Xcode build done.                                           13.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:132:3: error: control reaches end of non-void function
    [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
      }
      ^
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:134:3: error: expected identifier or '('
      if (networkCurrentRadioAccessTechnology) {
      ^
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:138:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else {
        ^
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:144:1: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
    }
    ^
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:156:35: error: no known class method for selector
    'archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:'
        resultData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/david/Documents/mics Featured-products 2/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORPlatform.m:213:45: error: no known class method for selector
    'unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:'
          unarchivedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:archiveClass
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 errors generated.
```

Comment: I suggest editing the question to explain the specific the steps you took to get to where you are now so that others could reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Firebase require at least Xcode 11. You can examine the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) to find older Firebase versions that work with older Xcodes.